# is usage from multifiltering with jQuery useful?

Tags: jquery

i got this code

```
$('.pBwarn div').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 60;
}).addClass("pB_yellow");

$('.pBwarn div').filter(function(index){
    return parseInt(this.innerHTML) > 80;
}).addClass("pB_red");
```

and want to know if it is useful? or maybe another way to realize this.

i want to change the **green** bar to **yellow** when percentage is larger than 60 (`id="max60"`) 
and change it to **red** if percentage is larger than 80 (`id="max80"`)

just want to say that the script is running perfect. i only asking if there is potential for improvement :D

you can check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TjHvT/)** for a better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally suggest:

```
$('.pBwarn div').addClass(function(){
    var num = parseInt((this.textContent || this.innerText),10);
    if (num > 80) {
        return 'pB_red';
    } else if (num > 60) {
        return 'pB_yellow';
    }        
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TjHvT/1/).

The anonymous function within `addClass()` will iterate over the elements returned by the selector, and, in each iteration, `$(this)`/`this` will refer to the current element; the benefit of this is that you need to call fewer jQuery methods (which reduces the time spent iterating/reiterating over the same set of elements).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Answer (score 3):

This type of question is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

However, instead of filtering the lists twice, I would just iterate once and check for both conditionals together.

```
$('.pBwarn div').each(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);

    if (val > 80) {
        $(this).addClass('pB_red');
    } else if (val > 60) {
        $(this).addClass('pB_yellow');
    }
});
```